Anyone know a dataset where we can get a metric relating to prescription drug sales tradename?
Does anyone know a data source that gets me revenue per drug tradename or something related/correlated to this?
I see medicaid has a utilization dataset which is seems related to revenue per tradename, but the dataset is only updated once a year. I need something that is at least quarterly.
I also am considering scraping quarterly reports of pharmaceutical companies to get the revenue for each drug product. But this is very difficult.
